# Telerik-RadWindow,RadAjaxManager and IE9 crash application

Tags: crash, telerik, internet-explorer-9, radwindow, radajaxmanager

I am using Telerik control,There two page List and Detail page.
Detail page opens Radwindow. After closing radwindow, ajaxrequest is refreshing grid of list page(parent page).

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" Height="665px" Width="1200px" runat="server"
            Modal="true" Behaviors="Close,Move" VisibleStatusbar="false" Title="Add Service" DestroyOnClose="true">
            <Windows>
                <telerik:RadWindow ID="rdwAddService" runat="server" Title="Editing record" ReloadOnShow="true"
                    ShowContentDuringLoad="false" Modal="false" DestroyOnClose="true" />
            </Windows>
        </telerik:RadWindowManager>
    </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" OnAjaxRequest="RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest" RequestQueueSize="0">
         <ClientEvents OnResponseEnd="responseEnd" />
        <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadAjaxManager1">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="grdTL" />
                     <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="grdTR" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>

 function RefreshGrid(SubServiceType) {

                if (SubServiceType == "TR") {
                             $find("<%=RadAjaxManager1.ClientID%>").ajaxRequestWithTarget( '<%= btnRefreshTRGrid.UniqueID %>', '');
                }
                else if (SubServiceType = "TL") {
                             $find("<%=RadAjaxManager1.ClientID%>").ajaxRequestWithTarget( '<%= btnRefreshTLGrid.UniqueID %>', '');
                }
            }
```

**

```
Now problem is
In IE9,after opening/closing radwinow five-six times,
1)does not load radwindow again, like application hangout
2)Other button stops working
3)On refersh page, application hangout and need to close browser instance.
```

**

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved issue of IE9 browser crash.

**Problem is** 
I am attaching close event of radwindow to pageLoad() function,so every postback, close function attached (ex 4 times) and called 4 times and in script grid are refreshing, so 4 times grid are refreshing and crashes application.

```
incorrect
    function pageLoad() {
            GetRadWindow().add_close(CallFnOnParent);
                }
```

**Solution is** 
Use Sys.Application.add_init function so, it is attach close event only first time and remove close event before close event.

```
correct
      Sys.Application.add_init(function () {
                    // Initialization code here, meant to run once.
                     GetRadWindow().add_close(CallFnOnParent);
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise on an even better approach - add the handler in the main page, as this is where the function should reside. You could then simply set it in the markup or when opening the popup. Then removing the close handler in itself is a great approach. Something like:

```
function openRw(){
var wnd = radopen();
wnd.add_close(myCloseHandler);
}

function myCloseHandler(sender, args){
sender.remove_close(myCloseHandler);
//other code
}
```